# ROC curve goes "Flat" (Python)

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, roc

I am trying to predict a binary variable using three methods (Logistic regression, KNN, and Random Forest) and tried making an ROC curve. It seems, however, that my ROC curve goes "flat" around 0.5 which seems quite odd. Here is my code:

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_features=1, n_jobs=-1)
rf.fit(x_train,y_train)
lg = LogisticRegression()
lg.fit(x_train,y_train)
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=20)
knn.fit(x_train,y_train)

rfprobs = rf.predict_proba(x_test[traincols])[:,1]
lgprobs = lg.predict_proba(x_test[traincols])[:,1]
knnprobs = knn.predict_proba(x_test[traincols])[:,1]

for pred_prob,name in zip([rfprobs, lgprobs, knnprobs],["RF","LG","KNN"]):
    fpr,tpr,thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, pred_prob)
    auc_score = roc_auc_score(y_test, pred_prob, average='macro', sample_weight=None)
    plt.plot(fpr, tpr, label = name+', AUC: '+str(round(auc_score,4)) )
    plt.xlim([0.0,1.0])
    plt.ylim([0.0,1.1])
    plt.title("ROC Curve")
    plt.xlabel("FPR")
    plt.ylabel("TPR")
    plt.legend()
```

Which yields the following ROC curve:
[image]

I can't figure out why this is the case. I always thought these curves should gradually go to (1,1).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This means there is a subset of the negative class wich can be completely seperated from the positive class in a way that the remaining negative cases together with all the positive cases have a ~ 50/50 ratio.

Comment: There is no inconsistency here.

Comment: @AlexR I've made your comment into an answer because I feel that it fully answers the question. If you'd like, you can write your own answer and notify me, and I'll delete this one.

Comment: I don't see how an ROC curve is helpful in this context.  Make a high-resolution histogram of the predicted risks.

Answer (score 2):

This means there is a subset of the negative class which can be completely separated from the positive class in a way that the remaining negative cases together with all the positive cases have a ~ 50/50 ratio.

---

> I've copied @AlexR's comment as an answer because the comment is, more or less, an answer to this question. We have a dramatic gap between answers and questions. At least part of the problem is that some questions are answered in comments: if comments which answered the question were answers instead, we would have fewer unanswered questions.
>
> - [Are we seeing a dramatic drop in answers per question?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2242/are-we-seeing-a-dramatic-drop-in-answers-per-question/5320#5320)
> - [Comments that are actually answers](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/832/comments-that-are-actually-answers)
> - [We have a very large & widening gap between questions and answers. How do we fix it?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5325/we-have-a-very-large-widening-gap-between-questions-and-answers-how-do-we-fix)